# Permission denied on resource project None on 1 thread only in tpu_cluster_resolver

Tags: python, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I'm running an BERT pretraining code on cloud TPUs from the Compute Engine.

Each time i run it, i get this error on 1 thread but the training continues normally.

I ran the same code on google Colab TPUs and it worked fine.

for the tpu_cluster_resolver im passing the IP address for the TPU instance, i also tried passing the zone and project name with the same results

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 476, in _fetch_cloud_tpu_metadata
    return request.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/None/locations/None/nodes/xxxxxx:8470?alt=json returned "Permission denied on resource project None.". Details: "[{'links': [{'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/project/None/apiui/credential', 'description': 'Google developer console API key'}], '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help'}]">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/preempted_hook.py", line 87, in run
    response = self._cluster._fetch_cloud_tpu_metadata()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 480, in _fetch_cloud_tpu_metadata
    "constructor. Exception: %s" % (self._tpu, e))
ValueError: Could not lookup TPU metadata from name 'b'xxxxxxxx:8470''. Please doublecheck the tpu argument in the TPUClusterResolver constructor. Exception: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/None/locations/None/nodes/xxxxxx:8470?alt=json returned "Permission denied on resource project None.". Details: "[{'links': [{'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/project/None/apiui/credential', 'description': 'Google developer console API key'}], '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help'}]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know without seeing the code.

By looking at the error "Permission denied on resource project None.", I would suggest you to add in the [TPUClusterResolver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/TPUClusterResolver?version=stable) the argument "project" with your Google Cloud project name as it seems to be filled with "None".